# Get a specific value from a list of web scraped results

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I built this code to **scrape** specific values from a website:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Brave Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36'
    }

url = "https://www.blockchaincenter.net/altcoin-season-index/#how30"
req = requests.get(url, headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
#print(soup.prettify())

b = soup.findAll('div', class_='bccblock')[:3]

print('\n--- selected: FULL LIST ---')
for i in b:
    full_list = list(i.stripped_strings)
    print(full_list)

print('\n--- selected: VALUES LIST ---')
for i in b:
    values_list = list(i.stripped_strings)[:2][1]
    print(values_list)
```

And the results are:

> --- selected: FULL LIST ---
>
> ['Altcoin Month Index', '61', 'Bitcoin Month', 'Altcoin Month']
>
> ['Altcoin Season Index', '8', 'Bitcoin Season', 'Altcoin Season', "It's Bitcoin Season!"]
>
> ['Altcoin Year Index', '55', 'Bitcoin Year', 'Altcoin Year']
>
> --- selected: VALUES LIST ---
>
> 61
>
> 8
>
> 55

How to just get the first value only - in this case 61?

Comment: Tangential to the question as you’ve posed it, but why have you included CORS headers in your request, and what *exactly* do you expect them to do in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-doing things here.

There's no need to iterate over `b` again and grab the values. The second `for-loop` is not at all required.

If you want values, you can get those from `full_list` in the first `for-loop` itself.

```
for i in b:
    full_list = list(i.stripped_strings)
    # prints the complete list
    print(full_list)
    # prints the values
    print(full_list[1])
```

If you want only the first value, then

```
first_val = list(b[0].stripped_strings)[1]
```